# How to run Volley in fragment(Navigation Drawer)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, connection, android-volley, navigation-drawer

I want to call volley by clicking new item in navigation drawer.
How to run Volley from Fragment?
I can run volley easily in activities but it is showing error in "this". i.e.

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

in above code
How to run volley in Fragment?
in Navigation Drawer?

I am doing this:

```
 public CollegesFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_colleges, container, false);


        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
   RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);



        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("TAG", "hello");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

please give me idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

before returning the rootView you need to add the following line:

```
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

You need to add the request to the RequestQueue.

Also, `Volley.newRequestQueue(context)` takes a Context as parameter. So you should pass the activity context or the application context.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very very much this one works for me.
simply i get required thing.
THANKS AGAIN.

Comment: Using ApplicationContext is suggested over ActivityContext.

Comment: @MehrdadSComputer well that depends. If you have some network requests that are specific to an activity/fragment, then activity context should be provided. If the network request is supposed to survive activity destruction, then pass application context. BTW, I'd not recommend using volley. Use retrofit

Answer (score 1):

you should refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html) link for more details on using RequestQueue.

**EDIT:**

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class
        .getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

use this method in your fragment

```
/**
 * Making json object request
 * */
private void makeJsonObjReq() {
    showProgressDialog();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            Const.URL_JSON_OBJECT, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", "Androidhive");
            params.put("email", "abc@androidhive.info");
            params.put("pass", "password123");

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
            tag_json_obj);

    // Cancelling request
    // ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag_json_obj);       
}
```

i hope this will help you...

Comment: I can't get idea.
i jsut want to abstract data through volley in fragment not in MainActivity   .

Comment: what is your response data, String or JSONObject or JSONArray or XML?

Comment: its JsonObject that i want to get from web.
i just want to display that data in toast,
i can display in activity easily by using same as googledevelopers but in fragment i cant :(

Comment: Let me check.
i am implementing, if anything happen i will inform you.
Thank you !!!

Comment: Thanks very much
i get the idea
THANKS

Comment: this is closer to a 'correct'  answer - shows how to create a RequestQueue in an activity and add requests to that from enclosed fragments; however the queue being instantiated in the main activity appears to be a singleton - it would be better if a proper queue were to be instantiated by instantiating the cache and network first.

Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
queue.start();